# Conditionally concatenate rows of a dataframe and process additional columns based on the condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have an Input Dataframe that the following :

```
NAME    TEXT                                            START   END
Tim     Tim Wagner is a teacher.                        10      20.5
Tim     He is from Cleveland, Ohio.                     20.5    40
Frank   Frank is a musician.                            40      50
Tim     He like to travel with his family               50      62
Frank   He is a performing artist who plays the cello.  62      70
Frank   He performed at the Carnegie Hall last year.    70      85
Frank   It was fantastic listening to him.              85      90
```

Want output dataframe as follows:

```
NAME    TEXT                                                                                                                            START       END
Tim     Tim Wagner is a teacher.  He is from Cleveland, Ohio.                                                                           10          40  
Frank   Frank is a musician                                                                                                             40          50
Tim     He like to travel with his family                                                                                               50          62
Frank   He is a performing artist who plays the cello. He performed at the Carnegie Hall last year. It was fantastic listening to him.  62          90
```

Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
grp = (df['NAME'] != df['NAME'].shift()).cumsum().rename('group')
df.groupby(['NAME', grp], sort=False)['TEXT','START','END']\
  .agg({'TEXT':lambda x: ' '.join(x), 'START': 'min', 'END':'max'})\
  .reset_index().drop('group', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    NAME                                               TEXT  START   END
0    Tim  Tim Wagner is a teacher. He is from Cleveland,...   10.0  40.0
1  Frank                               Frank is a musician.   40.0  50.0
2    Tim                  He like to travel with his family   50.0  62.0
3  Frank  He is a performing artist who plays the cello....   62.0  90.0
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks @scott-benson for you help.

Comment: Is it possible to combine only upto "n" rows at a time (say 3 rows into 1 row) . @scott-benson any suggestions on how this can be done